# How to Change Quickly's Editor?

Tags: command-line, python, application-development, quickly

I've just downloaded [Ninja IDE](http://ninja-ide.org/) and I really like it's interface.

Is there a way to configure the Quickly app to launch my project in Ninja IDE when I type *quickly edit*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`quickly` should support the `EDITOR` environmental variable.

```
$ quickly help ubuntu-application edit
Usage: quickly edit

A convenience command to open all of your python files in your project 
directory in your default editor, ready for editing.

If you put yourself EDITOR or SELECTED_EDITOR environment variable, this latter
will be used. Also, if you configured sensible-editor, this one will be
choosed.
```

I don't have any other GUI IDEs installed, but I tested it with `$ export EDITOR=nano && quickly edit` and all files were opened in `nano` instead of `gedit`. Adding `export EDITOR=nano` to your `~/.bashrc` should make this change persistent.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm new to Linux: Does ~/ mean the root level?  Where do I find the .bashrc file?

Comment: `~/` is shorthand for the current user's home folder. So if your user name is "nootrino" it expands to `/home/nootrino/` The `.bashrc` file is hidden from view most of the time as all files or folders starting with a dot ("`.`") are. Open your home folder and press `Ctrl + h` to expose these hidden configuration files, often referred to as "dot files."

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to change the default editor for your system you could just use

```
export QUICKLY_EDITOR="yourpreferrededitorhere"
```

I found this somewhere on the net, so credits go to the guy who discovered this solution.

Cheers